# Google Analytics API: find next pages viewed after a particular page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using the Google Analytics API, is there any way I can find the pages users viewed **immediately after** a particular page?

I know how to get the previous page (ga:previousPagePath) and the exit page from the session (ga:exitPagePath), but not the next page.

Currently, the only way I can get this data is from the Visitor Flow page in the API, but I'd really like a way to automate it - creating reports manually is very slow.

The only other way I can think to do this is to find every page flow in the site, and then reverse engineer it - but it would be really nice to have it in the API.

Comment: the dimension named ga:nextPagePath, is it of some use over here ?

Comment: Figured it out - set `previousPagePath` to the page you're interested in, and then look at `nextPagePath`.